# How can I run a command on every file in a given directory?

Tags: linux, bash, mp4box

I am using `mp4box` to move the MOOV atoms on MP4 files.

The thing is, I will have 6 files in a given folder and I don't want to run the `inter 500` command six separate times.

Is it possible to do something like `mp4box -inter 500 *` in a directory to have the command run on all the mp4 files in that folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` option of `find`. Here, `'{}'` is replaced with the file name of every MP4 file. This will deal with all kinds of file names, even those containing spaces or newlines. You need to supply `-maxdepth 1` to only search the current directory.

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -maxdepth 1 -exec mp4box -inter 500 '{}' \;
```

An alternative, more convoluted way would involve piping the output from `find` into a loop with `read`. Here, every file is delimited by the `NUL` character, and you need to tell `read` to split the input on this character, which is achieved by `-d ''`. You also need to quote the variable `"$file"`, so spaces or globbing characters in the name are retained.

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do mp4box -inter 500 "$file"; done
```

Comment: after running the above, i get this: `ce_002.mp4: unknown primary or operator` am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is that your file names contain weird characters... Try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your updated answer! works great. I should read more up on exec :).

Comment: I made a few corrections. The globbing pattern in `-name` should always be quoted. Otherwise the `*` glob will be expanded before `find` even sees it. This means the command would fail if you were searching in another directory than the current one, or going deeper than one level. Also, the `-exec` option deals with any kind of filename. Using `xargs` is not really necessary—the `while` loop works better, but here the output should be null-delimited.

Comment: thanks for your edit and details, this works flawlessly!